# Using fscanf: Finding a char in an input

Tags: c, loops, if-statement, while-loop, scanf

While doing some practice for an upcoming assignment I ran into a problem using fscanf and trying to throw a notice when the incorrect format is entered into the program. I'm pretty sure I have to use the return of fscanf, but can't figure out how to use it inside my while loop. Currently the program loops continuously when a value such as "a3" is entered, yet "3e" works almost fine, except it outputs the number 3 twice.

Working scanf code:

```
int intGet( int min, int max ) {

int input = 0;
char temp = ' ';
printf("Enter a number in between [%d-%d]: ", min, max);

if (scanf("%d%c", &input, &temp) != 2){
    errorNo = 1;
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
if (temp != '\n'){
    errorNo = 2;
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
if (input < min || input > max){
    errorNo = 3;
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
else {
    printf("Read %d\n", input);
}
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
```

fscanf code along the same idea, which loops continuously:

```
int intGet( int min, int max ) {
int counterValid  = 0;
int counterInvalid = 0;
int entry = 0;
int total = 0;
int input = 0;
int check = 0;
char temp = ' ';
FILE *fp;

fp = fopen("02_num.txt", "r");
if (!fp)
{
    perror("fopen()");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
printf("----------------------------------------------------------\n");
printf("Entry\tInvalid\tValid\tNumber\n");
printf("----------------------------------------------------------\n");

fscanf(fp, "%*[^\n]\n"); //skips first line (min and max)


  while (check != EOF){

check = fscanf(fp, "%d%c", &input, &temp);

    if (check == EOF){
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }
    if (check != 2){
        counterInvalid += 1;
        entry += 1;
        printf("%d\t*\t\t%d\tIncorrect Format\n", entry, input);
    }
    if (temp != '\n'){
        counterInvalid += 1;
        entry += 1;
        printf("%d\t*\t\t%d\tExtra Characters\n", entry, input);
    }
    if (input < min || input > max){
        counterInvalid += 1;
        entry += 1;
        printf("%d\t*\t\t%d\tInput Number out of Range\n", entry, input);
    }
    else{
        counterValid += 1;
        entry +=1;
        total += input;
        printf("%d\t\t*\t%d\n", entry, input);
    }
}
     printf("----------------------------------------------------------\n");
entry +=1;
printf("%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\n", entry, counterInvalid, counterValid, total);
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

This code will then output a table that looks something like this:

```
*****************************************************
       Entry    Invalid    Valid    Number
         1         *                  32
*****************************************************
// adds invalid and valid entry totals, displays then here, adds totals of valid numbers and also outputs them here.
```

02_num.txt file that was being used in this code, first two numbers are the min and max, read in another function.

```
1 15 //min and max
23 
45 
67 
8990  
3e 
12 
a3
```

Things I have tried to work with the if/while loop:

Defining a variable to record the return value of fscanf (currently the closest):

```
while (check != EOF){

check = fscanf(fp, "%d%c", &input, &temp);
    if (check != 2){
        counterInvalid += 1;
        entry += 1;
        printf("%d\t*\t\t%d\tIncorrect Format\n", entry, input);
    }
```

Checking the return value in the if statement as well (scans the file twice and doesn't output properly):

```
while (fscanf(fp, "%d", &input) != EOF){

    if (fscanf(fp, "%d%c", &input, &temp) != 2){
        counterInvalid += 1;
        entry += 1;
        printf("%d\t*\t\t%d\tIncorrect Format\n", entry, input);
    }
```

If there is any information I am missing please let me know, i'm just a bit stuck here.. have been for the past couple days. Probably just a stupid mistake i'm missing but thanks in advance!

Comment: First of all, if you want to read a whole line why don't you use e.g. `fgets` instead of `scanf`? Secondly, most `scanf` format specifiers (for example all numeric formats) read and discard leading white-space.

Comment: When `a3` is read, the `%d` fails on the `a`, and then the next attempt fails on the `a`, and so does the next.  The `3e` case works because the `%c` reads the `e`, and the `%d` on the next iteration skips the white space (newline).  Don't use `scanf()` et al for line based input; it doesn't care about line boundaries.  Use `fgets()` (or `getline()`) and `sscanf()` instead.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I know fgets will work better, but the objective is to get familiar with more primitive forms of I/O. I'm limited in this case to fscanf

Comment: I wouldn't call `scanf` (and family) "more primitive", quite the opposite in fact. No other I/O function does as much processing of the input as `fscanf`. If you wanted more "primitive" forms of I/O you would have used the low-level platform-specific I/O functions directly instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with the loop is what you do when `fscanf` returns zero. Among other things, it means that if you call `fscanf` again with the same format string, the result is going to be zero, because the problem in the input that lead to you getting zero in the first place has not been addressed.

You need to add code for skipping the line when you get zero back from `fscanf` - for example, your `fscanf(fp, "%*[^\n]"); fscanf(fp, "%*1[\n]");`, as modified by [Jonathan Leffler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15168/jonathan-leffler) and [chux](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2410359/chux), will work.

Comment: Note that the trailing `\n` (or any trailing white space) in the format string will read white space (including newlines) until it comes across a something that's not white space.  That's dire if the input is interactive.  It would be better to use `%*[\n]`, I believe; that's a non-assigning read of a single newline.  The only gotcha is that you can't tell whether the `%*[\n]` actually matched — it isn't counted in the return value.  (OTOH: it is unlikely to matter — it can only fail on EOF without a final newline.)

Comment: (I've removed my "funny (peculiar)" comment — the `scanf()` failed on an empty line (no character to satisfy the first conversion specification of `"%*[^\n]%*1[\n]"` on an empty line.  I'm relieved; it's much easier to fix the bug in my thinking than to fix a bug in the o/s.)  This should go too, soon.

Comment: `fscanf(fp, "%*[^\n]%*1[\n]");` will fail if the first character read is not a `'\n'`.  the simple fix to consume _optional_ leading non-`'\n'` is `fscanf(fp, "%*[^\n]"); fscanf(fp, "%*1[\n]");`

Comment: @chux Thank you for the comment!